# how to display whether the number is a multiple of 4 or not using loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

The question is:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer and displays whether the number is a multiple of 4 or not. The program stops reading integers, when the user inputs a negative value. It shows at the end the total number of values entered which are multiple of 4.

Here is my progress so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
int n; 

while ((n = input.nextInt()) >= 0) {
    if ( n%4 == 0) {
        System.out.print(n + " is a multiple of 4");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(n + " is not a multiple of 4");
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't how to let the loop to keep executing until the user types in `0`.

Comment: Your question didn't ask you to stop executing at `0`, just negative numbers. Your code is already correct.

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
while((n = input.nextInt()) >= 0)
```

to

```
while((n = input.nextInt()) != 0)
```

This will keep the loop running until a zero is entered

Comment: Though this answer answers the question about executing until the "the user type in 0", the original requirements  were that the it stopped when "the user inputs a negative value." Not sure this answer fully hits the requirements.

Comment: This question is so basic and so obvious that there really is no reason for anyone to gain reputation from answering it. It's pretty much in the "typo" category.

Comment: So don't give him any reputation. Downvoting something because you don't want someone else to give it reputation is not what it is for.

Comment: The question follows all the guidelines required for a valid question. Just because many of us know the answer doesn't mean others shouldn't ask it. He asked a question when he had a doubt. If you know the answer then help him otherwise let others show their dedication.  These days SO is a place for downvoting and flagging rather than answering and helping  others.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `0` isn't a negative number, so you don't need to stop at `0`. Your code is correct!